# Analog GCC '-ffshort-double' in Clang

Tags: c, gcc, clang

There is an option '-fshort-double' in GCC, Clang does not understand it. Is there some analog of this option for Clang 3.7 ?

Comment: I got 'minus' for this question. Could you please comment it - it is very simple question, or something else? I really don't know how to change my compiler from gcc to clang, just remove this option and thats it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in looking at the web page: `https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html#Option-Summary`,

there is no `-fshort-double` option in `gcc`.

therefore, the option is not valid to begin with.

suggest removing that option when changing to `clang`

Comment: Seems to be yes, just removing, it is kind a "target-specific flag" https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2014-09/msg02515.html